# How to have the same behaviour of F5 when reload in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I want the same behavior than :

> ui-sref-opts="{reload: true}"

or F5

With something i can use in my controller.

I try this :

> $state.transitionTo(myStateIWhantToReload, $stateParams, {reload:true,
>   inherit:false})

But it don't reload wholly :/

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to use,

```
$state.reload();
```

it would refresh the current state. But if you have parent-child state scenario in your current page then you could use

```
$route.reload();
```

it will reload the controllers but not services.
if you want to reload whole page then use

```
$window.location.reload();
```

Hope it would help